# Splitting an RGB uint into its separate R G B components

Tags: language-agnostic, colors, bit-manipulation

I have an RGB colour stored as a uint. I can create this from the RGB values using the bitwise left and bitwise or operator in an expression like this:

```
colour = r<<16 | g<<8 | b;
```

I want to do the opposite. I have the final number and I want the r, g and b values. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your quick answers. All 3 are correct. I guess you were all typing at the same time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
r = (colour >> 16) & 0xff;
g = (colour >> 8) & 0xff;
b = colour & 0xff;
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```
r = ( colour >> 16 ) & 0xFF;
g = ( colour >> 8 )  & 0xFF;
b = colour & 0xFF;
```

Assuming 8-bit component values.  The bitwise-and hex `0xFF` masks pick out just the 8-bits for each component.

Answer (score 4):

You use shift, and then the & operator to mask out unwanted bits:

```
r = color >> 16;
g = (color >> 8) & 255;
b = color & 255;
```

Alternatively:

```
b = color & 255;
color >>= 8;
g = color & 255;
r = color >> 8;
```